# batch script to create users from csv

Tags: batch-file

I am not able to create users, I would like to take the first letter of their firstname and the whole of their surname as userid. (my script is in french)

Here it is:

```
echo off chcp 28591 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion rem je fait la creation de l'ou

for /f "skip=1 tokens=4,5 delims=;" %%A IN (listes_apprenants.csv) DO (

set organisation= %%A set service= %%B

dsadd ou "ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" dsadd ou "ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" dsadd group "cn=gg_!service!,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" dsadd ou "ou=utilisateur,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" )

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8* delims=;" %%A IN (listes_apprenants.csv) DO (

set prénom= %%A set nom= %%B set site= %%C set organisation= %%D set service= %%E set adresse= %%F set téléphone= %%G set bureau= %%H

dsadd user "cn=!prénom:~0,1!!nom:~0,19!,ou=utilisateur,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" -disabled no -pwd Pilote01 -fn !prénom! -ln !nom! -memberof "gg_!service!,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" -dept !site! -tel !téléphone! -office !bureau! -mustchpwd yes )
```

***[3rd party edit]***

```
echo off
chcp 28591
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem je fait la creation de l'ou
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4,5 delims=;" %%A IN (listes_apprenants.csv) DO (
    set organisation= %%A
    set service= %%B
    dsadd ou "ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan"
    dsadd ou "ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan"
    dsadd group "cn=gg_!service!,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan"
    dsadd ou "ou=utilisateur,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan"
)
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8* delims=;" %%A IN (listes_apprenants.csv) DO (
    set prénom= %%A
    set nom= %%B
    set site= %%C
    set organisation= %%D
    set service= %%E
    set adresse= %%F
    set téléphone= %%G
    set bureau= %%H
    dsadd user "cn=!prénom:~0,1!!nom:~0,19!,ou=utilisateur,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" -disabled no -pwd Pilote01 -fn !prénom! -ln !nom! -memberof "gg_!service!,ou=!service!,ou=!organisation!,dc=pme,dc=lan" -dept !site! -tel !téléphone! -office !bureau! -mustchpwd yes
)
```

Comment: basicly i would like to know if the name Virgile Laroche with the commande "cn=!firstname:~0,1!!name:~0,19!" would give Vlaroche ?

Comment: You've posted some code, which was invalid, _and has been fixed by me by way of edit_, and told us what you're not able to do, but have not asked a specific question. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59425562/edit), _(not include it in the comment area)_, to include a full and proper explanation of which specific issue in your batch-file you'd like us to assist you with.

Comment: It may also be worth checking that you really want code page 28591, _(`ISO 8859-1 Latin 1; Western European (ISO)`)_, as opposed to code page 850, _(`OEM Multilingual Latin 1; Western European (DOS)`)_ or more likely code page 1252, _(`ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows)`)_.

Comment: i have found my error it should be !prénom:~1,1!!nom:~1,19!

Comment: You don't need to set all of those variables either, just `Set "prénom=%%A"`. e.g. `dsadd user "cn=!prénom:~,1!%%B,ou=utilisateur,ou=%%E,ou=%%D,dc=pme,dc=lan" -disabled no -pwd Pilote01 -fn %%A -ln %%B -memberof "gg_%%E,ou=%%E,ou=%%D,dc=pme,dc=lan" -dept %%C -tel %%G -office %%H -mustchpwd yes`, should be necessary. And you can also use `tokens=1-8` instead of `tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8*`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some typos in the edit, also some redundant code so I am re-writing it here.

No need to change anything other than prenom, as all other items can be used directly.

Also the way it was assigning variables was adding spaces which would have lead to results you likely did not want, further we don't know if you have double quotes `"` around the values in the CSV, which we don't want to have inside rhe `DN` strings which are double quoted as a whole, ans which we may need on the strings for the user fields.  So I am providing them.

The "NOM" portion of the CN is usually the entire surname, there is no reason to restrict these to 20 characters.

The 20 Character limit is in the SAMID, but as you are not specifying a SamID, it auto generates to the first 20 characters if not specified.  :)

(This is the behavior you commonly see in the GUI when typing in long user names)

```
@(setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  echo off
  chcp 28591
  rem je fait la creation de l'ou
  SET "_Filte=C:\Pah\To\listes_apprenants.csv"
  SET "_Base_DN=dc=pme,dc=lan"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /B
)

:Main

  for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-8 delims=;" %%A IN ('
    Type "%_File%"
  ') DO (
    dsadd ou "ou=%%~D,%_BaseDN%"
    dsadd ou "ou=%%~E,ou=%%~D,%_BaseDN%"
    dsadd group "cn=gg_%%~E,ou=%%~E,ou=%%~D,%_BaseDN%"
    dsadd ou "ou=utilisateur,ou=%%~E,ou=%%~D,%_BaseDN%"
    set "prénom=%%~A"
    dsadd user "cn=!prénom:~0,1!%%~B,ou=utilisateur,ou=%%~E,ou=%%~D,%_BaseDN%" -disabled no -pwd Pilote01 -fn "!prénom!" -ln "%%~B" -office "%%~H" -mustchpwd yes -memberof "cn=gg_%%~E,ou=%%~E,ou=%%~D,%_BaseDN%" -dept "%%~C" -tel "%%~G"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I am new to this and didnt know i could just do that